# convert phone number into words

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

So I figured out that I can count through the hash, the problem is that for 7 and 9 I have four values. I have tried several other things with no luck. Can someone help understand what else I could do to get the values I want out of the hash. I realize that I can match the numbers with the key, but I am confused how to get the values to permute.

```
letters = {"1" => ["1", "1", "1"],
       "2" => ["a", "b", "c"],
       "3" => ["d", "e", "f"],
       "4" => ["g", "h", "i"],
       "5" => ["j", "k", "l"],
       "6" => ["m", "n", "o"],
       "7" => ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
       "8" => ["t", "u", "v"],
       "9" => ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}


phone_number = gets.chomp.to_s

words = []
word = []

numbers = phone_number.chomp.chars

count0 = 0
while count0 < 3
  count1 = 0
  while count1 < 3
    count2 = 0
    while count2 < 3
      count3 = 0
      while count3 < 3
        count4 = 0
        while count4 < 3
          count5 = 0
          while count5 < 3
            count6 = 0
            while count6 < 3
              word[0] = letters[numbers[0]][count0]
              word[1] = letters[numbers[1]][count1]
              word[2] = letters[numbers[2]][count2]
              word[3] = letters[numbers[3]][count3]
              word[4] = letters[numbers[4]][count4]
              word[5] = letters[numbers[5]][count5]
              word[6] = letters[numbers[6]][count6]
              words << word.join
              count6 += 1
            end
            count5 += 1
          end
          count4 += 1
        end
        count3 += 1
      end
      count2 += 1
    end
    count1 += 1
  end
  count0 += 1
end
puts words
```

---

Edit:

I want to a seven digit number and print out all possible letter combinations. I am a beginner so I want to understand with the things I know now. I want to try and do this with `if` statements please.

```
numbers = phone_number.chomp.chars

if letters.key?(numbers[0])
 if letters.key?(numbers[1])
  if letters.key?(numbers[2])
   if letters.key?(numbers[3])
    if letters.key?(numbers[4])
     if letters.key?(numbers[5])
      if letters.key?(numbers[6])

      end
     end
    end
   end
  end
 end 
end
```

I understand how to grab a value from a matching key, but don't get how I can hold the first value while going through the rest, if that makes any sense.

Comment: I either misinterpreted the original question or it has changed, my answer is more of a reverse of the question, except you have a string you want to validate a against, you might be chasing a wild goose here as Matt's answer shows below

Comment: Do you want real words, or do you want combinations of letters that result from substituting the letters the numbers point to? Generating combinations of letters is a lot easier than getting real words which takes a good sized dictionary.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea what your question is.  Considering that there are several answers, however, the authors of those questions evidently understood your question, so I suspect that at some point you edited out your original question.  If I am correct, please do not do that.  It makes the question nonsensical to anyone who did not see the original version, including possibly hundreds of SO users who read your question in future.  Please re-edit to make it clear what your question is.  In future, when you edit your question, include something like "Edited:...".

Comment: I want to enter a 7 digit number, then print out all possible letter combinations. Real words don't matter I have a file I want to compare to.

Comment: @user2963093 It seems you have additional requirements, since my answer does that..

Comment: Not sure how to use those particluar 7 `if` blocks since they are always true assuming valid input. My guess is that you are looking for nested iterative blocks instead - see my updated answer.

Comment: Man do I have a lot to learn, I knew that I could get the key I wanted by doing letters[number]. I didn't realize I could use a .each to iterate through it, along with doing it 7 levels deep. I've learned a lot from this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

`product` is the function you are looking for, the following works with any number of digits:

```
digits = '27'
keys = digits.chars.map{|digit|letters[digit]}
p keys.shift.product(*keys).map(&:join) #=> ["ap", "aq", "ar", "as", "bp", "bq", "br", "bs", "cp", "cq", "cr", "cs"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This prints all possible words for a variable-sized phone number:

```
letters = {"1" => ["1"],
       "2" => ["a", "b", "c"],
       "3" => ["d", "e", "f"],
       "4" => ["g", "h", "i"],
       "5" => ["j", "k", "l"],
       "6" => ["m", "n", "o"],
       "7" => ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
       "8" => ["t", "u", "v"],
       "9" => ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}

digits = gets.chomp.split ''

# Total number of combinations
n = digits.inject(1) { |a,b| a * letters[b].size }

words = []
0.upto n-1 do |q|
  word = []
  digits.reverse.each do |digit|
    q, r = q.divmod letters[digit].size
    word.unshift letters[digit][r]
  end
  words << word.join
end

puts words
```

For example, if the input is `67`, then there are 12 combinations:

> mp mq mr ms np nq nr ns op oq or os

Edit: I don't see a way to make use of the 7 `if` statements as you have written, but perhaps this is closer to the kind of answer you are looking for:

```
words = []
letters[digits[0]].each do |c0|
  letters[digits[1]].each do |c1|
    letters[digits[2]].each do |c2|
      letters[digits[3]].each do |c3|
        letters[digits[4]].each do |c4|
          letters[digits[5]].each do |c5|
            letters[digits[6]].each do |c6|
              words << [c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6].join
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

puts words
```

A good exercise would be to re-write this in a way that can work for phone numbers of any length, not just 7. Again, this is only for instructional purposes. In practice, one would use Array's [`product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-product) method as in [hirolau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20376555/2700898).

Comment: Is there a way I can put it into 7 if statements?

Comment: Yes. This sounds like homework - I don't want to rob you of this valuable education by doing it for you :) hopefully this answer gives some insights.

Comment: Without deleting your current question, add an "Edit:" and make an attempt at your "7 if statements" or whatever direction you want to go in. Then we can make further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
LETTERS = {"1" => ["1", "1", "1"],
   "2" => ["a", "b", "c"],
   "3" => ["d", "e", "f"],
   "4" => ["g", "h", "i"],
   "5" => ["j", "k", "l"],
   "6" => ["m", "n", "o"],
   "7" => ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
   "8" => ["t", "u", "v"],
   "9" => ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}


def convert_to_phone_number(string)
  string.each_char.with_object([]) { |x, arr| LETTERS.each { |k,v| (arr.push k; break) if v.include?(x) }}.join
end

convert_to_phone_number "foobar"
#=> "366227"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think so it is issue of cache memory
 u need to change like below

```
LETTERS = {"1" => ["1", "1", "1"],
   "2" => ["a", "b", "c"],
   "3" => ["d", "e", "f"],
   "4" => ["g", "h", "i"],
   "5" => ["j", "k", "l"],
   "6" => ["m", "n", "o"],
   "7" => ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
   "8" => ["t", "u", "v"],
   "9" => ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}


def convert_to_phone_number(string)
  string.each_char.with_object([]) { |x, arr| LETTERS.each { |k,v| (arr.push k; break) if v.include?(x) }}.join
end
```

convert_to_phone_number "foobar"